# Jquery - On input, Get the value of a span inside a td using span class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a spam changed by the user (using contenteditable),
through its class.
The spam is inside a `<td>` in a table.

I tried `let newItemName = $(variantId).children(".item-description").text();`
and also `let newItemName = $(variantId).find('span.item-description').text();`
which both return an empty string to `newItemName` variable.

Any ideas why I'm getting an empty string instead of the users input?

**This is my JS:**

```
let variantId;
$(document).on('click', ".tbl-itemClass", function () {
    variantId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);

}).
    on('input', function () {
        //let newItemName = $(variantId).children(".item-description").text();
        let newItemName = $(variantId).find('span.item-description').text();
    });
```

**This is my .csHtml** (don't think it makes a difference, I'm using razor page, Asp.Net)

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr currentitemid=" @item.Id">
        <td class="tbl-itemClass desc" id="@("description"+ item.Id)" varianttype="@ViewBag.VariantType" >
            <span class="spnSpc">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="width:90%; padding:1px 5px 1px 2px;" **class="item-description"** contenteditable> @item.Description </span>
        </td>
        
        <td class="tbl-itemClass ">//more code here
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

`@item.Description`s value is a color (i.e: 'red').
When the user changes that value (i.e: 'redX'), this code runs, but returns an empty string instead of 'redX'.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You select the element again with the `variantId` variable. But that is only a string and won't select the element, because the string doesn't contain the # when selecting elements with an id.

```js
variantId = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
```

Now `variantId` will be #+your_id

Comment: Thanks! This really helped! (I didn't think in that direction because `$(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);` worked.

Comment: Yeah that has to do with the way this and context works in js. It's vague.

Comment: How come this code `$(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);` works best ONLY as a string, and on the other hand the span value returns ONLY when adding the '#' as you suggested?

Comment: I'm really not sure javascript is an ambiguous language and jQuery is an old libray. You could take a look into jQuery's source code if you really want to know.

Comment: I just realized `$(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);` didn't work. 
The reason why I thought it did, is because the `<span>` contained a contenteditable attribute. 
```<span style="width:90%; padding:1px 5px 1px 2px;" class="item-description" contenteditable > @item.Description </span>```